# Computing $\sum_{m=0}^{l} {{k-l}\choose{m}}{l\choose m}x^m$

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Given that $k \ge 0$ and $0 \le m \le l \le k$, how does one simplify the expression
\begin{align*}
\sum_{l=0}^k (-1)^l\left[\sum_{m=0}^{l} {{k-l}\choose{m}}{l\choose m}x^m\right] u^{k-l} v^l,
\end{align*}
given that $x$ here is actually a variable that depends on $u$ and $v$?

The hard part for me is simplifying the inner sum, which looks like Vandermonde identity but it is not the same. I have tried to consider generating function but I am stuck as well. Any idea would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Actually if you want $(u-v-x)^n= \sum^n_{i,j,k}(^n_{i,j,k})u^iv^jx^k$ then you need something close to the summation that you have.

Comment: Have you tried generating functions with a new variable $y$?

Answer (score 0):

*This is probably too long for a comment.*

$$\sum_{m=0}^{l} {{k-l}\choose{m}}{l\choose m}x^m=P_l^{(0,-k-1)}(1-2 x)$$ where appears the [Jacobi polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_polynomials).

It could also be expressed as $$\sum_{m=0}^{l} {{k-l}\choose{m}}{l\choose m}x^m=\, _2F_1(-l,l-k;1;x)$$ where appears the [Gaussian or ordinary hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).